# Configure browser cache in SFSafariViewController using Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, browser-cache, sfsafariviewcontroller

In my application I am implementing a feature where for some part I need to open my website using SFSafariViewController. For this I don't want the user to login again in the web application as well, so before I open the SFSafariViewController I want to pass some token, mail and other required information. So is this feasible and would allow me to use browser cache.

Answer (score 5):

`SFSafariViewController` is very limited in what you can configure, as seen by the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller. Apple intentionally keeps cookies and safari configuration separate from apps that are using it for security and privacy reasons.

I don't know if this is exactly what you're seeing, but I faced a similar issue where, if a user logged in via `SFSafariViewControler`, then logged out (not using `SFSafariViewController`), then logged in again, it wouldn't ask for a login/pass because it was still cached in the browser.

Pretty much the only 2 options for this are:

1. Have the logout flow take place within `SFSafariViewController` so that you can clear the cookies that way.
2. Apple has a new auth flow class `ASWebAuthenticationSession` (docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession)) which has a new property you can set called `prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession` which essentially opens the browser in private mode. This keeps any cookies from being stored in the browser. The only downside to this, is the `prefersEphemeralWebBrowserSession` property is only available in iOS 13+.

If this is the same issue you're facing and you can limit your app to iOS 13+, then I would suggest the `ASWebAuthenticationSession` route, otherwise you may need to find another solution.